# How to see the values that scalacheck is generating?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I am using scalatest and scalacheck to do some property based testing. I'm new to both scala and these libraries so pretend this code is much less ugly that it actually is.

I have a test like this:

```
class MyTests extends FlatSpec with Checkers {

  "My Class" should "Do something interesting" in {
    check((e1 : String, e2 : String, e3 : String) =>
      doInterestingThing(e1, e2, e3))
   }

  def doInterestingThing(e1: String, e2: String, e3: String) : Boolean = {
    val myClass = new MyClass[String]
    val passed = myClass.Foo(e1, e2, e3)
    passed
  }
}
```

How do I see the values that scalacheck is generating? I'm currently running the test like this:

```
scala -cp "../lib/scalatest.jar:../lib/scalacheck.jar:." org.scalatest.run MyTests
```

But all I get is pass/fail output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
"My Class" should "Do something interesting" in {
  check { (e1: String, e2: String, e3: String) =>
    println(s"doInterestingThing($e1, $e2, $e3)")
    doInterestingThing(e1, e2, e3)
  }
}
```

---

As a side note, this line in your original code:

```
check((e1: String, e2: String, e3: String) => doInterestingThing(e1, e2, e3))
```

could be rewritten as:

```
check(doInterestingThing)
```

Comment: I thought there might be an option for scalacheck, but this should work too. Thanks

Comment: you can easily create a helper or macro to scrap the boilerplate in this one if you do this frequently.